# Android: How to avoid ImageView flashing when the screen is clicked?

Tags: android

I have an `ImageView` on the screen that I've scaled. When I click on the screen, the image goes back to its original size, and then the scaled size, and then back again constantly. Any ideas on how to fix this? Or why this is happening?
My code for the `ImageView's` fragment

```
public class LargeFragment extends Fragment {
    Button back;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.large,container,false);
        final ImageView p = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.large);
        final SharedPreferences pref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("high",0);
        p.setImageResource(getResources().getIdentifier(pref.getString("selectedPlayer","pink").concat("large"), "drawable",view.getContext().getPackageName()));
        view.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                p.requestLayout();
                final int w = view.getWidth();
                p.getLayoutParams().height = w; //scaling the image here
            }
        });
        back = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.exit);
        back.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                LargeFragment.this.getActivity().finish();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg2">
   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/large"
       android:rotation="270"
       android:scaleType="fitCenter"
       android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
      />
    <Button
        android:text="Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/exit" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

use `android:scaleType` in xml or `ImageView.setScaleType()` to scale the image. I think `centerCrop` is what you need.

see [android:scaleType](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:scaleType) to get more information.

Comment: Um 'android:scaleType' is already in my xml. I got what I needed, it's just that the image flashes when I click on it and I don't know why.

Comment: so why do you call `requestLayout()` and `p.getLayoutParams().height` in the runnable method?

Comment: i need to make sure that the view is rendered or else 'view.getWidth' will be 0, and 'p.getLayoutParams().height=w' in the runnable is to make sure 0 isn't assigned to it. as for 'requestLayout()' I'm not sure google said so. But how does this relate to what my problem is? : /

Comment: the `setImageResource()` will call `requestLayout()` if it needs. that means you have called `requestLayout()` twice, so i guess that's why it will reset the size.

Comment: But why would the application run the code again when I click the screen? I didn't set 'onClickListeners' or anything on the 'ImageView'

Comment: so the image will not change its size if you dont click the `ImageView` ?

Comment: Nope it wouldn't. Let's say the image was size A, after scaling it's size B(what I want). It is displayed as size B. When I click on it, or hold the screen, it goes from B->A->B->A->B->A.....